# Why I can't se my network printer inside an app accessed via Citrix web client?

Tags: printing, citrix, network-printer

I'm using citrix web client to access some apps and from them I can't print to my network printer.
Citrix redirects my local usb atached printer just fine, but it doesn't redirect my network printer.

What do I need to do, that I will be able to use my network printer from citrix ?

Best regards, Primoz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend putting in a ticket to ask the Citrix admin if this is possible with their setup.  Depending on the Citrix server version and config many things could be in the way:

1. Admin has only enabled local printer redirection and not network printer redirection
2. Admin has not enabled Universal Printer Driver and there is no driver on Citrix for your specific printer.
3. Admin has set Citrix to try to print to printers directly and you are not on the same network as Citrix and somehow it's tripping Citrix up (I think it should fallback to redirection).

Note that if you and Citrix are on the same network you should be able to add a printer while in Citrix to print directly from Citrix to that network printer.

Comment: Me and Citrix are on totaly different networks. I use an app provided by another company and this app runs on their citrix server. Problem is that admins at that company are not citrix gurus and they don't have much clue what to do. So I'm doing their work and trying to find some answers.

Comment: @Bret Fisher
Ok, they told me that they use XenApp 4.5. Can you please write some short guide where to find settings mentioned in you answer.
Or just tell for which terms should I search on google to get relevant hits, because I'm not familiar with citrix terminology.
Thank you very much.

Comment: http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/index.jsp?topic=/xenapp6-w2k8-admin/ps-printing-planning.html

Comment: http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/index.jsp?topic=/xenapp6-w2k8-admin/ps-printing-configuring-wrapper.html

Comment: They can use the help docs to determine how they have it setup.  In the end if they can't figure it out you have two options you can control.  Everything you print you can print to your local XPS printer wich will save your print job as a file on your computer, where you can then print to the network printer.  Or, add a new local TCP/IP printer and point to the network printer's IP.  That's a different way of setting up a network printer that should count as a "local printer".

Comment: I don't know exactly what they do, but they found your answer and links helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Citrix expert, just a user of a VPN app, but maybe this helps:  In our case, only the Windows Default Printer gets exported to Citrix, and no other. Changing the printer means disconnecting, switching the default printer and connecting again. This is regardless of the printer being connected via network or local.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in my case this doesn't help. 
Citrix redirects all local printers (my usb printer and windows XPS printer) no matter if they are default or not, but never redirects network printer.